# S3 generic method not appearing in package manual

Tags: r, generics, roxygen2

In my R package, a few functions are omitted from the package manual .pdf file - and they are all S3 methods where several functions are documented together.  All other "normal" functions appear correctly, so I suspect I'm not documenting the S3 methods correctly.

I want an entry for `myfun` to appear in the manual. Right now, the function is missing from the .pdf manual entirely, though it can still be called correctly and its help page referenced with `?myfun`. Are my Roxygen2 keywords wrong?

```
#' @export
myfun <- function(...) UseMethod("myfun")

#' @inheritParams myfun
#' @describeIn myfun Create a frequency table from a vector.
#' @export
#' @keywords internal

myfun.default <- function(vec, sort = FALSE, show_na = TRUE, ...) {
...
}

#' @inheritParams myfun.default
#' @describeIn myfun Create a frequency table from a data.frame,
#' supplying the unquoted name of the column to tabulate.
#' @export
#' @keywords internal
tabyl.data.frame <- function(.data, ...){
...
}
```

(I omitted the `@title, @description, @param, @return, @examples` lines to keep this question shorter but can edit them in if relevant).

The generic methods are exporting as intended, so that the user only sees `myfun()` and not `myfun.default()` or `myfun.data.frame()`, unless they use the triple colon `:::`.  I'd like to retain that behavior, so the user just calls `myfun`, while also having an entry for `myfun` in the package manual.

Comment: Right now, `myfun` doesn't appear at all in the manual.  I don't want sections for `myfun.default` and `myfun.data.frame`, I just want an entry for `myfun` in the manual - I'll make that clearer in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed `@keywords internal` in the two `myfun.` methods and that did it: `myfun` appears in the package's manual.  I also switched to `@rdname myfun` instead of `@describeIn myfun`, to eliminate the section *"Methods (by class):"* in the function's documentation.

What made this hard to isolate was that if I run `devtools::document()` and then don't restart the session, the methods `myfun.data.frame` and `myfun.default` are visible in RStudio's autocomplete and can be called directly.  They are not supposed to be accessible to the user, and I thought my Roxygen2 documentation was to blame.

In fact, all I had to do was remove `@keywords internal`.

The methods `myfun.data.frame` and `myfun.default` *do* appear in the autocomplete after typing `?`, e.g., `?myfun.default`, but I think there's no way around that (and it directs to the single help page for all three `myfun` functions, anyway).  This is standard.  For example, `?print.aov` is a visible help file while `print.aov()` cannot be called directly.